# Linear Algebra vector matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[Link to the picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZZwx.png)

[image]

So, do I simply put the numbers in a augmented matrix and into row echelon form, and solve for m? The variable m throws me off.

Comment: That's exactly why teachers have these kind of questions. So you need to do this Row Echelon manually...The nature of the problem suggests that the given vectors are linear dependent, otherwise there would be no constraint for m

Comment: I think $m$ can be any value you like...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $-v_2+v_3$ will get the second coordinate of $w$ for you, but the first coordinate won't be right, so which multiple of $v_1$ would you need to add to fix it? Once you get the first two coordinates matched up, read off the third coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. You want $w$ to be a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ so we need:

$$
\left( \begin{matrix} 1&-5&4 \\ 0&2&-3 \\ 2&5&1 \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} a\\b\\c  \end{matrix} \right)= \left( \begin{matrix} 3\\-5\\m \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Row reducing the augmented matrix gives you this:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0&0&\frac{7m-74}{31} \\ 0&1&0&\frac{3m+71}{31}\\ 0&0&1 & \frac{2m+63}{31} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

So you can make $m$ whatever you like and then the last column of the matrix above will give you the $a,b,c$ values that you need for the linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

An easy way to see that any value of $m$ will do is to note that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ so any vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear combination of them.